# Can an event horizon be distorted temporarily by a passing star?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

If a star travels past a black hole and then continues on (i.e. does not merge into the black hole), how does it affect the shape of the event horizon of the black hole during this temporary period? Does the event horizon distort away from the star?

The event horizon is often defined as the surface for which the net gravitational force is above a certain value (sufficient to prevent light from escaping). But gravitational forces are cumulative, and the star has its own gravitational force; when the star is closest to the black hole, the net gravitational attraction towards the black hole is reduced on the side nearest the star, and increased on the other side. The event horizon would be distorted to be smaller on the star side and larger on the other side.

Does this mean theoretically that a photon that was previously within the event horizon could now be outside the event horizon, for the duration of this gravitational distortion? In other words, theoretically, could it escape the black hole when there is an external gravitational pull?

Comment: When a heavy object approaches a black hole, the event horizon expands. In your logic, instead of subtracting forces, think of adding gravitational potentials. Also, everything at the horizon moves with it, so nothing is consumed by this movement.

Comment: safesphere - do you have article that shows why everything moves with the horizon? It's an interesting concept indeed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an article, but this is self evident anyway. A rock flying toward a BH never crosses the horizon. Per the relativity principle, this is the same as a BH flying toward the rock and pushing it away. No matter how you look at it, moving or not, everything stays at the horizon forever.

Comment: When two black holes merge, we get gravity waves coming out. Does that mean the one black hole went into the other, and that it didn't stay on the EH?

Comment: You should address your comments like this: @Dean (no spaces). Otherwise no one may be notified. What you are asking in your comment is different from your question. Comments are for clarifications, but not for questions or answers. You would get a better response if you post a separate question.